# Angular: disable field on change and set value of field

Tags: angular, forms, onchange, onsubmit, angular2-form-validation

I have a table in which I need to render database values and then after user changes I need to submit that form. Here is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flu1fo?file=src/app/app.component.html)

There I need to apply like,
if status is 'eliminated' or 'absent' then need to disable rank dropdown and  rank will be null/0.

I am able to render details and tried on change of status to disable rank but it not working.

Please help and guide. Thanks.

**Ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  myForm!: FormGroup;
  rankArray = [];
  rankStatusArray: any = [
    { id: 'participated', name: 'Participated' },
    { id: 'eliminated', name: 'Eliminated' },
    { id: 'absent', name: 'Absent' },
  ];
  checklist = [
    {
      id: 13,
      rank: 3,
      horse_id: 86,
      horse_name: 'test232 fdfgdg',
      life_number: null,
      country: 'Afghanistan',
      result_status: 'participated',
      comment: 'my comment',
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      rank: null,
      horse_id: 87,
      horse_name: 'test horse',
      life_number: '234234',
      country: 'Algeria',
      result_status: null,
      comment: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      rank: null,
      horse_id: 88,
      horse_name: 'tesdfs',
      life_number: null,
      country: 'Afghanistan',
      result_status: null,
      comment: null,
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      rank: null,
      horse_id: 94,
      horse_name: 'nam horse',
      life_number: 'fh345',
      country: 'India',
      result_status: null,
      comment: null,
    },
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      checklist: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    this.populate();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rankArray = Array(4)
      .fill(1)
      .map((x, i) => i + 1);
  }

  get formChecklist() {
    return this.myForm.get('checklist') as FormArray;
  }

  populate() {
    this.checklist.forEach((x) => {
      this.formChecklist.push(
        this.fb.group({
          participantId: x.id,
          rankStatus: x.result_status,
          rank: x.rank,
          comment: x.comment,
          horse_name: x.horse_name,
          country: x.country,
          life_number: x.life_number,
        })
      );
    });
  }

  onChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event == 'eliminated' || event == 'absent') {
      this.myForm.controls['rank'].disable();
    } else {
      this.myForm.controls['rank'].enable();
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive competition_wrapper">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <table
      class="
        bordered
        border-top-0
        table
        dark
        shadow_none
        w-100
        mb-3
        competition_result_table
      "
    >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="150" colspan="6">Competition Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody formArrayName="checklist">
        <tr class="table_sub_heading">
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>Rank</td>
          <td>Participant Name</td>
          <td>Country</td>
          <td>Life Number</td>
          <td>Comment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr
          *ngFor="let item of formChecklist.controls; let i = index"
          [formGroupName]="i"
        >
          <td>
            <div class="select_wrapper form-group mb-0">
              <select
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="rankStatus"
                (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
              >
                <option [ngValue]="null">Select</option>
                <option
                  *ngFor="let status of rankStatusArray"
                  [ngValue]="status.id"
                >
                  {{ status.name }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="select_wrapper form-group mb-0">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="rank">
                <option value="null">Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let rankno of rankArray" [value]="rankno">
                  {{ rankno }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>{{ item.get('horse_name').value }}</td>
          <td>
            {{ item.get('country').value }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ item.get('life_number').value }}
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group mb-0">
              <textarea
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="comment"
              ></textarea>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn">Add Result</button>
  </form>
</div>

<pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're enumerating a ton of points and since this is not a free code provider app, I won't be solving them all until, at least, you try to do something.

This being said, I created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdiewy?file=src/app/app.component.html) that solves the first problem I see you tried and couldn't finish. You weren't able to disable the rank field because:

- first, the event you're passing in the *onchange* function is not what you want. You need the event's value and even then, you need to extract the information that's important to you, the id.
- second, you were trying to disable/enable something that didn't exist. The console was giving you errors about it. ***this.myForm.controls['rank']*** is undefined.

Regarding step n.4, you might need to be listening to the rank *formcontrol* and hide the chosen options from the next competitor's rank dropdown. Hope this gives you a hint to tackle the problem.

Comment: Sorry for asking a ton of points. Thanks for help and guiding me. I have edited my question on the part that I have tried. I checked your solution. Its disabling rank but from result also rank gets removed. can we get there 'null' or 0 somehow?

Comment: I think that's just a matter of setting the value to null when you disable the rank.

Comment: I tried  `(this.formChecklist.controls[index] as FormGroup).controls[ 'rank'  ].setValue(0);`   but after disabling, rank attribute getting removed so its not showing in `<pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre>`

Comment: I've updated the demo. That happens because the formcontrol is disabled, thus the value doesn't show up in the form's value. And that makes sense. Anyway, if you don't need the value (null), there's not a problem in not sending it to the backend later on.